# powershell: Check if any of a bunch of properties is set

Tags: powershell

I'm importing a csv-file which looks like this:

```
id,value1.1,value1.2,value1.3,Value2.1,Value2.2,Value3.1,Value3.2
row1,v1.1,,v1.3
row2,,,,v2.1,v2.2
row3,,,,,,,v3.2
```

Now I want to check, if any of the value-properties in one group is set.

I can do

```
Import-Csv .\test.csv | where {$_.Value1.1 -or $_.Value1.2 -or $_.Value1.3}
```

or

```
Import-Csv .\test.csv | foreach {
    if ($_.Value1 -or $_.Value2 -or $_.Value3) {
        Write-Output $_
    }
}
```

But my "real" csv-file contains about 200 columns and I have to check 31 properties x 5 different object types that are mixed up in this csv. So my code will be realy ugly.

Is there anything like

```
where {$_.Value1.*}
```

or

```
where {$ArrayWithPropertyNames}
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily use the Get-Member cmdlet to get the properties which have the correct prefix (just use `*` as a wildcard after the prefix).

So to achieve what you want you could just filter the data based on whether any of the properties with the correct prefix contains data.

The script below uses your sample data, with a `row4` added, and filters the list to find all items which have a value in any property starting with `value1`.

```
$csv = @"
id,value1.1,value1.2,value1.3,Value2.1,Value2.2,Value3.1,Value3.2
row1,v1.1,,v1.3
row2,,,,v2.1,v2.2
row3,,,,,,,v3.2
row4,v1.1,,v1.3
"@
$data = ConvertFrom-csv $csv

$data | Where {
    $currentDataItem = $_
    $propertyValues = $currentDataItem | 
        # Get's all the properties with the correct prefix
        Get-Member 'value1*' -MemberType NoteProperty |
        # Gets the values for each of those properties
        Foreach { $currentDataItem.($_.Name) } |
        # Only keep the property value if it has a value
        Where { $_ }
    # Could just return $propertyValues, but this makes the intention clearer
    $hasValueOnPrefixedProperty = $propertyValues.Length -gt 0
    Write-Output $hasValueOnPrefixedProperty
}
```

Comment: works.+1 for showing that the where-scriptblock can do more than $_.xy -eq z. As this is not very common (at least for me ;-) I've put that in a sub-function. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution:

```
$PropsToCheck = 'Value1*'

Import-csv .\test.csv | 
 Where {
  (($_ | Select $PropsToCheck).psobject.properties.value) -contains ''
  }
```